# Encoding error in Python

Tags: python

Trying to make an encode process but have an error line:

Look at my whole fuction ,please, for the whole getting it. I think it isn't big enough.

Trying to add the header to the file data:

```
#Add the header to the file data
    headerdata = struct.pack("4s"+\
                             "I"+\
                             str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+"s",header.magicnum, header.size, header.fformat)
    filebytes = headerdata + data
```

**Have an error:**

> str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+"s",header.magicnum, header.size, header.fformat)
>   struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object

I was trying to change it:(this line, addin 'b')

```
str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+b"s",header.magicnum, header.size, header.fformat)
```

**Have another error:**

> str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+b's',header.magicnum, header.size, header.fformat) TypeError: must be str, not bytes

**the whole fucnton:**

```
def encode(image, data, filename, encryption=False, password=""):
    im = Image.open(image)
    px = im.load()

    #Create a header
    header = Header()
    header.size = len(data)
    header.fformat = "" if (len(filename.split(os.extsep))<2)\
                     else filename.split(os.extsep)[1]

    #Add the header to the file data
    headerdata = struct.pack("4s"+\
                             "I"+\
                             str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+"s",header.magicnum, header.size, header.fformat)
    filebytes = headerdata + data

    #Optional encryption step
    if encrypt:
        if password:
            filebytes = encrypt(filebytes, password,\
                                padding=im.width*im.height - len(filebytes))
        else:
            print ("Password is empty, encryption skipped")

    #Ensure the image is large enough to hide the data
    if len(filebytes) > im.width*im.height:
        print ("Image too small to encode the file. \
You can store 1 byte per pixel.")
        exit()

    for i in range(len(filebytes)):
        coords = (i%im.width, i/im.width)

        byte = ord(filebytes[i])

        px[coords[0], coords[1]] = encode_in_pixel(byte, px[coords[0],\
                                                            coords[1]])

    im.save("output.png", "PNG")
```

Comment: Your error has to do with the other arguments, not the format string. It's saying that where in the format string there is an "s", it is expecting a bytes object. check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) out, look at section 7.1.2.2

Comment: what are the types for header.magicnum, header.size, header.fformat

Comment: @jacoblaw      it should be `str`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code

since you said they are all strings, here you go

```
headerdata = struct.pack("4s"+\
                             "I"+\
                             str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+"s",header.magicnum.encode(), int(header.size), header.fformat.encode())
```

This should work for the formats and types you want

## Explanation

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), and specifically section 7.1.2.2, we can find the types needed as arguments for the following format characters:

```
-----------------------------------------
|Formatting Character | Type (in python)|
-----------------------------------------
|s                    | integer         |
-----------------------------------------
|I                    | bytes           |
-----------------------------------------
```

and since the data you want to format is of type `str`, we need to change it.

Lets start with making a `str` to and `integer` since it's the simplest.

```
>>> x = '123'
>>> type(x)
str
>>> y = int(x)
>>> type(y)
int
```

Easy, all we need to do is call `int()` on our string.

Next up is turning a string into bytes. We use strings `encode()` method to do this [(documentation)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html)

```
>>> x = '123'
>>> type(x)
str
>>> y = e.encode()
>>> type(y)
bytes
>>> print(y)
b'123'
```

Comment: @x20 added the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Your original code was correct, except that the type of `header.magicnum` was unexpected.  Your code snippet should read

```
#Add the header to the file data
    headerdata = struct.pack("4s"+\
                             "I"+\
                             str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+"s","{:04d}".format(header.magicnum).encode('UTF-8'), header.size, header.fformat)
    filebytes = headerdata + data
```

or some other suitable format code and encoding that turns `header.magicnum` into your expected result.

Comment: Can't get. Is there some missing of ` "  `  in your answer?

Comment: Yes there is, fixed.

Comment: have another error, urghhhhhhh ;(((( 
It writes: `ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'`

Comment: If header.magicnum is already a string, then just use `header.magicnum.encode('UTF-8')`; this will convert the string into a `bytes` object (and get rid of the `"{:04d}".format()` part).

Comment: Doing smth like this `str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+"s",header.magicnum.encode('UTF-8'), header.size, header.fformat)
struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object`

walking around one place.. if it's `str`, trying to `encode` , why does it want bytes object?

Comment: The format string you are specifying is indeed a string, which is why str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH) is working; you are just adding on to the string that begins "4s" + "I".  In python 3, there is now a strong (and useful) distinction between bytes and strings.

Comment: You'll need to make sure that the subsequent argument types match the types specified in the struct, with the caveat that the string types expect bytes instead of strings.  Therefore, you'll also need to `encode` your `header.fformat` field (which is being packed as a string) and you will need to make sure `header.size` is an integer (e.g., if it is a string, you'll need to call `int(header.size)` to make sure it is an integer first.

Comment: Ohhh, I see, I can get it now, Thank you your answer and explaination. Can I ask you the last question ,please, I'm on my way to build it. I'm using Python 3 , as you said. And have problem with `color = (r+(pixel[0]&252),\ g+(pixel[1]&252),\ b+(pixel[2]&252),\a(pixel[3]&252))`. It says, that IndexError: tuple index out of range. I think, it is because of that I'm using ver num 3, yeah? Sorry for that, if you can help..I think < i need to remove `a`

Comment: It looks like `pixel` (which I assume is a tuple) does not have enough elements; my guess would be that you have three elements in pixel (i.e., it's missing an alpha channel) and when you try to get element 3 in `pixel[3]&252` you are generating the 'index out of range' error.